# Nginx - redirect to a new url based on the Payload

Tags: nginx, url, dynamic

I have a scenario in my project where the incoming request will be http:///MailService.aspx with a XML Payload. I have to interpret the payload and look for a tag mail. Based on the value of the tag, proxy_pass the url to  http:///signin or http:///mail

Sample Payload:

```
<Request>
<CommandType>send</CommandType>
<From>test@abc.com</From>
<To>test@new.com</To>
</Request>
```

Incoming URI: http:///MailServices.aspx

Nginx Conf:

```
location /MailServices.aspx {
        proxy_pass http://<domain>/mail;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    }
```

Am looking for a solution like below within nginx conf,

if(commandType is 'mail') uri = http:///mail
if(commandType is 'signin') uri = http:///signin

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.